# SQL Query performance with inner queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure whether the title of this question is correct or not.

I have a table for example `users` which contains different types of users. Like user type `10, 20, 30` etc.

In a query I need to join the `user` table, but I want only user type 20. So which of the below query perform better.

```
 SELECT fields 
 FROM consumer c 
 INNER JOIN user u ON u.userid = c.userid
 WHERE u.type = 20
```

In another way,

```
 SELECT fields 
 FROM consumer c 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT user_fields FROM  user WHERE type = 20) u ON u.userid = c.userid
```

Please advice.

Comment: the first     ..direct  join perform  bette then join with subselect

Comment: You should test both on your database and see.  Most likely there will be little to no difference.  MSSQL server is pretty good at optimization.

Comment: Never really sure how to answer these. But the first one should do, logically, as you are just throwing in a complexity with a nested select. Check the execution plans of both to see what is actually going on, the answers will be in there.

Comment: You could move the u.type=20 on the "ON" clause of the INNER JOIN. It would look like this `INNER JOIN user u ON u.type=20 AND u.userid = c.userid`

Comment: My doubt is, in the second result we are limiting the resultset so the number of records will be less. So it should perform fast right?

Comment: My rule of thumb is "Don't try to be smarter than the RDBMS".

Comment: Prolly no difference, compare plans when in doubt

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with this query:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM consumer c INNER JOIN 
     user u
      ON u.userid = c.userid
 WHERE u.type = 20;
```

Assuming that `type` is relatively rare, you want indexes on the tables.  The best indexes are probably `user(type, userid)` and `customer(userid)`.  It is possible that an index on `user(userid, type)` would be better (and would be unnecessary if `userid` is a clustered primary key).

The second query . . . well, from the SQL Server perspective it is probably the same.  Why?  SQL Server has a good optimizer.  You can check the execution plans if you like.  Because of the optimizer:

1. There is no benefit to having a subquery select only a handful of columns.  For better or worse, SQL Server pushes that information down to the node that reads the data.
2. The `where` clause is not necessarily going to be evaluated before the `join`.  SQL Server is smart enough to re-arrange operations.

Not all optimizers are this smart.  In a database such as MySQL, MS Access, or SQLite, I'm pretty sure the first version is much better than the second.

Comment: As per Microsoft Guidelines, more than five tables are not allowed to join in SQL Server. Is it correct? If not correct, as per your perspective how many tables are allowed to join in SQL Server for better performance.

Comment: @RGS . . . That is definitely not correct, or almost all the real code I've written in SQL Server would not run.  Where would you find such misguided guidelines?

Comment: Microsoft technical team has been reviewed our SQL code and told that more than five tables you put in join performance degradation will occur if table records grow. When they reviewed our code,  I was not there. If I was there, I will definitely raise the question to prove that one. That is why I have asked to you to clarify that one. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @RGS . . . I think there is a limit in SQL Server where if you have fewer than `n` joins, it does an exhaustive search of all possible joins to determine the best execution plan.  Otherwise, it resorts to heuristics.  Perhaps that has something to do with what they were saying.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on a various number of factors:

- is "userid" on both table indexed?
- is "type" on table "users" indexed?
- how many rows in each table?

Usually a subquery produces slower performances, but depending on the conditions listed above and how your sql server installation is configured, both query can be resolved (and so, executed) as the same by the query analyzer.

SQLServer takes your query and tries to optimize it so it can happen that query B is "transformed" in query A.

Look at the QueryAnalyzer tool for both queries, and see if they have differences.

Generally speaking inner queries are better to be avoided, and you'll probably get the best performances doing query A.

Answer (score 1):

Run the two queries in SSMS as a batch, and click "execution plan" , you will find that the execution plan of both queries, and the query cost (relative to the batch ): 50%

That means they are the same.

If they are different (in case of some optimization), you find the ratio different.

I simulated your query and find the query cost=50% ===> i.e they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both your options are valid. Personally would code it like this;

```
SELECT fields 
FROM consumer c 
INNER JOIN user u ON u.userid = c.userid and u.type = 20
```

Run both queries in SQL Management Studio (query) and tick 'Include actual execution plan'. This will let you see the performance of your queries against each other. It will depend on your particular database.